# C# How to get a generic type from a dynamic variable

Tags: c#, generics

Supposing I have:

```
public Dictionary<CertainEnum, Type> myDictionary = new()
{
    { CertainEnum.A, typeof(Class1) },
    { CertainEnum.B, typeof(Class2) }
}
```

How could I call a method that uses generics using this dictionary? I tried to declare 'testVariable' as either a 'Type' or 'dunamic', but the error is the same: 'testVariable is a variable but is is used like a type'.

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public List<T> MyMethod()
    {
        return new List<T>();
    }
}

dynamic testVariable = myDictionary[CertainEnum.A];
var result = MyClass.MyMethod<testVariable>();
```

By reading this extensive post:

> [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)

... what I was not able to find is how to deal with the fact that 'result' gets a List.

Comment: You cannot use variables as generic type parameters, this includes `testVariable.GetType()`.

Comment: `testVariable` will always reference an instance of `System.Type`. Using `dynamic` achieves nothing here, other than remove type safety. If you want to invoke `MyMethod` using a `System.Type` at runtime, you need to use reflection.

Comment: Generics are determined during compile time, but the value of `testVariable` is only known at runtime. You will need a non-generic overload of `MyMethod<T>()` that takes the type as a parameter: `MyMethod(Type)`.

Comment: "what I was not able to find is how to deal with the fact that 'result' gets a List." why not?